# Managed C++ Wrapper - How to to expose the Method with pointers as arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-studio-2005

I am writing a managed c++ wrapper. 
It has a method with arguments as pointers. 
How to expose this type of method?
Eg: void Test(float* salary);

Comment: Try this, I didnt try it just wrote out of my head.

[DllImport(@"yourDll.dll")]
private static extern void Test(ref float salary);

Comment: you need to pass pointers between managed C++ and .NET? If so try using `long` type to pass pointers. Between unmanaged C++ and C++/CLI you can just use float*.

Comment: @TerentyRezman Yes, I need to pass the pointers between managed c++ and .Net. Can you share any link for reference. I am new to this language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pointers in C are notoriously ambiguous.  Is it a pointer to a single float value?  Is it actually an array?  Does the float get passed in?  Or out?  Or both?  It matters when you need to write the pinvoke declaration.

Comment: @HansPassant It is an Array. Yes, The float passed in.

Comment: I'd be seriously concerned how the C code could possibly guess the size of the array.  Very unsafe.  Anyhoo, just declare it as float[].

Answer (score 1):

You shared too little information to be sure, but I would try one of the following:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
private static extern void Test(ref float salary);
```

or

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
private static extern void Test(IntPtr salary);
```

The last one in case, when you don't bother about the parameter's value or its type (though in case of float, I guess, that the first option is more likely).

You can also use C++/CLI and simply use pointers like in regular C++ project.